# Removing the double arrow for web part connections

Tags: 2010, web-part, image-display

I have two Web parts that I connected to each other to pass some filter variables. It achieved the goal I was hoping for, but when the connection was added a double arrow was placed by SharePoint in the top left hand corner. Is it possible to remove this image?

I tried just deleting through designer like I did for column headers, but that didn't work.

Messing around, I see no real point in the arrow other than indicate that it is connected to another web part and would really like to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the arrow you can select the row and pass it to the connected webpart. If you want to hide the images, then you can use following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img[src='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif']").hide();
    $("img[src='/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif']").hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response Amal, you seem to be answering alot of my questions.  Unfortunately I went to put your script in via designer, and when I saved the changes Designer stopped responding, I brought Designer back up and removed the edits I made...but when I saved that I could not open the page and the code in sharepoint has massive blocks of (seemingly gibberish) blue code. this section of this blue code is included in the <webpartsPages:WebPartZone tag

Comment: I thought I did as I had used it in the past, I will definitely look into use the Content Editor Web Part. However, for now I am just going to worry about salvaging/fixing the page so it dosent error out when trying to open

Comment: I managed to salvage the page! Also, I did what you recommended and made a copy of the page and have been working with that. I went back and made sure I had jquery installed, I also put in a CEWP linked to a .txt with your script.  Unfortunately it did not work, I pulled up dev tools and changed the background color with script so I know Jquery is loading but when I run your script through the consol i get a "Expected ')' error. I am not very savy with jscript (yet) so I am not sure as to the issue.

Comment: I was looking into it alittle more and notice there was an open parenthesis that missing its closing parenthesis, I added that in and now states that its looking for an open {

Comment: If you are testing in dev tools then you can try this `$("img[src='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif']").hide();$("img[src='/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif']").hide();`

Comment: Sorry, I made that comment before seeing your edit. your updated answer did the trick! thanks for all your help, and I will be marking your answer as correct